# Fill area between curve and line

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, fill

I want to fill the space between my curve and the 0 axis with a shadow but I am doing something wrong... If I try with the block below get the shadows but the reference line is not the one I want.

```
plt.figure()
plt.fill(hr,EfMeridMean,'gray')
plt.xlabel('Tempo (LT)')
plt.xlim(0,24)
plt.xticks(dim)
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylabel('UXef (m/s)')
plt.title(u'Vento efetivo líquido (BV+CX+CG)')
plt.savefig(path[9] + 'UXefliq_LT_nwm')
plt.clf() 
plt.gcf()
plt.close()
```

This is the output when I plot as above:
[image]

If I use the fill_between_demo.py example (see bellow) to plot I get the following error: "ValueError: Argument dimensions are incompatible"

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
ax1.fill_between(hr, 0, EfMeridMean)
ax1.set_ylabel('between y1 and 0')
ax2.fill_between(hr, EfMeridMean, 1)
ax2.set_ylabel('between y1 and 1')
plt.show()
```

How can I plot it properly?

Comment: What are `hr` and `EfMeridMean`  Are they of compatible shape?

Comment: it's a vector with the same size as hr = np.linspace(0.,24.,97)... Actually it is the data to plot the curve

Comment: What line does the error come from?

Comment: the first fill_between

Comment: Please print `hr.shape` and `EfMeridMean.shape`. Probably one of them isn't a 1D array, but has an extra dimension (which might be 1, and therefore works with `fill()`, but not here).

Comment: Also, just a general comment, in the spirit of being helpful: it's useful if you provide a minimal code block that can actually produce your issue.  Here, for instance, `hr` and `EfMeridMean` are arrays that you've set somewhere but not as part of this snippet.  And, conversely, the `xticks` and `xlabel` and `ylabel` and `savefig` are all skew to the conversation — they aren't part of what produces the error.

Comment: hr.shape is (97,) whilst  EfMeridMean.shape is (97, 1)...

Comment: There we go.  `EfMeridMean[:,0]` or `EfMeridMean.squeeze()` will fix it.

Comment: Yes, that solves the problem... Thank you!!